# FREAK is not a member of cv?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I am trying a code from tutorial to test the marker-less AR experience with OpenCV + OpenGL. But the problem is that when I compiled the code I found out that there is an error with the following segment of code:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::FREAK(false, false),
```

and the error is:

```
FREAK is not a member of cv.
```

So, can someone tell me why is that happening? I have tried to search for a solution and tried to solve as much as I can but every time I got error.

Comment: just check the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/db4/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1FREAK.html):  `cv::xfeatures2d::FREAK`

Comment: I have tried to change it to what you have written, but again I found this error:     ‘FREAK’ is not a member of ‘cv::xfeatures2d’

Comment: have you compiled opencv with contrib modules?

Comment: Also, do you have the right version of OpenCV? Did you include the appropriate header file?

Comment: Yes, I have compiled with the following headers:
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp>
and the OpenCV version is 3.4.0

Comment: `#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>`

Comment: @MohammadAlbardaweel Possible to share the link to the tutorial?